# How can I get my entire history with chrome.history.search?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am building an extension that reads through the Chrome history and analyzes the link for keywords.

I am using the `chrome.history.search` method to retrieve the browser history like so:

```
chrome.history.search({
        'text': '',
        'maxResults': 500,
    }, function(historyItems){
    });
```

At this point, I store the URLs retrieved in an array and begin reading through them.

But I am not getting everything. The number of URLs retrieved vary with different runs. I tried experimenting with the parameters in the search method, but I am not able to influence the number of links returned.

Can anyone help me understand this?

EDIT: When I say I am not getting everything, what I mean is compared to my browser history that I can see, the one pulled through the extension is much more limited.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73812) that Justaman mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044106/4200446) reveals that passing `maxResults: 0` will actually return *all* history items.  So if you really wanted the entire history, you could do:

```
chrome.history.search({ text: "", startTime: 0, maxResults: 0 }, 
    items => console.log(items));
```

I haven't tried that, as I expect that loading my tens (?) of thousands of history items into memory would take down Chrome.  But I did try it with a `startTime` of a few days ago, and that returned 645 items.

If you happen to be using the handy [chrome-promise](https://github.com/tfoxy/chrome-promise) library, here's a version of Antony's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262748/4200446) that uses promises instead of callbacks to loop through the API calls until the desired number of history items is found:

```
import ChromePromise from 'chrome-promise';

const chromep = new ChromePromise();

function loop(fn)
{
    return fn().then(val => (val === true && loop(fn)) || val);
}

function getHistory(requestedCount)
{
    var history = [],
        ids = {};

    return loop(() => {
        var endTime = history.length &&
                history[history.length - 1].lastVisitTime || Date.now();

        return chromep.history.search({
            text: "",
            startTime: 0,
            endTime: endTime,
            maxResults: 1000
        })
            .then(historyItems => {
                var initialHistoryLength = history.length;

                historyItems.forEach(item => {
                    var id = item.id;

                        // history will often return duplicate items
                    if (!ids[id] && history.length < requestedCount) {
                        addURLs(item);
                        history.push(item);
                        ids[id] = true;
                    }
                });

                    // only loop if we found some new items in the last call
                    // and we haven't reached the limit yet
                if (history.length > initialHistoryLength && 
                        history.length < requestedCount) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return history;
                }
            });
    });
}
```

You could use this function like this:

```
getHistory(2000).then(items => console.log(items));
```

Comment: 10k history items are not a problem whatsoever for a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I wrote to try and retrieve all history items using search. Give it a try and see if this helps:

```
var nextEndTimeToUse = 0;

var allItems = [];
var itemIdToIndex = {};

function getMoreHistory(callback) {
  var params = {text:"", maxResults:500};
  params.startTime = 0;
  if (nextEndTimeToUse > 0)
    params.endTime = nextEndTimeToUse;

  chrome.history.search(params, function(items) {
    var newCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.id in itemIdToIndex)
        continue;
      newCount += 1;
      allItems.push(item);
      itemIdToIndex[item.id] = allItems.length - 1;
    }
    if (items && items.length > 0) {
      nextEndTimeToUse = items[items.length-1].lastVisitTime;
    }
    callback(newCount);
  });
}

function go() {
  getMoreHistory(function(cnt) { 
    console.log("got " + cnt);
    if (cnt > 0)
      go();
  });
}
```

Comment: The `if (item.id in itemIdToIndex) continue;` bit is key.  I was confused by the duplicates I was getting back in the results.  Their information seems to be identical, so it's not clear why the API returns them, but they can be filtered out by building an index of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73812

you need to add startime

```
  var microsecondsBack = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days;

  var startTime = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsBack;
```

Comment: Since the OP wants the *entire* history, `startTime` should be set to 0.